# C#/aspx.net process Post Values form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm quite new on aspx development, and I'm struggling a lot with the connection of aspx code and aspx.cs, precisely I've following problem :

DisplayChars.aspx :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>   
    <div>Champion name: </div> <div><input id="Champ_name" type="text" /></div>
    <div>Champion Icon URL: </div> <div><input id="Champ_icon" type="text" /></div>
    <div>Champion Subtext: </div> <div><input id="Champ_subtext" type="text" /></div>
    <div> Free to play :</div><div><input id="Champ_freetoplay" type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div>Positions:</div>
<div>
        <input id="Top" type="checkbox" /> Top
        <input id="Mid" type="checkbox" /> Mid
        <input id="Jungle" type="checkbox" /> Jungle
        <input id="Carry" type="checkbox" /> Carry
        <input id="Support" type="checkbox" /> Support
</div>
</div>
    <input id="Champ_Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

DisplayChars.aspx.cs

```
 if (IsPostBack)    
        {
            //NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form.GetValues
            //Champion t1 = new Champion(Request.Form.Get("Champ_Name"), Int32.Parse(Request.Form.Get("Champ_freetoplay")), Request.Form.Get("Champ_subtext"), Request.Form.Get("Champ_description"), "10110");
            //t1.persistChampion();
            string temp = Request["Champ_name"];
```

So I'm struggling with getting the Form-values some how. 
I've tried `Request.Form.GetValues`,`Request.Form.Get` even `Request["Form_id_Name"]`.

The Question is, if this approach is even right, as I've experience in Object-oriented programming, but not in this combination of HTML aspx pseudo server code, and a cs-file behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `runat="server"` to you HTML tags and you can access their properties from the code-behind:

```
// DisplayChars.aspx:
<input id="Champ_name" type="text" runat="server" />
...

// DisplayChars.aspx.cs:
string champName = Champ_name.Value;
```

Comment: thank you so much, was kind of obvious, because i had a hidden textbox which already hat this property!

Answer (score 1):

While you can do

```
Request.Form["Champ_name"]
```

It is not the asp.net way. You have to make the element a server control by adding `runat="server"` so you can reference it from code behind.

```
<asp:Button ID="Champ_name" runat="server" OnClick="button_Click" Text="Hello World" />
```

Then in your codebehind can add a method to fire when that button is clicked:

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   // logic processing here
}
```

If you needed to find out what the text of the button is:

```
string text = Champ_name.Text;
```

Basically, ASP.NET doesn't rely on `Request.Form` normally. You set the controls to `runat="server"` so you can address them directly from code-behind on postback.